# pyscript @when decorator - js conversion

Tags: touch-event, pyscript

Trying to add some advanced interaction to my input field by making mouse motion scrub the value.
but having difficulty converting js to python within events.

any guidance ?

I have this:

```
@when("pointerup", selector=".scrubbable-num")
def nodrag(evt):
    evt.target.dragging = None

@when("pointerdown", selector=".scrubbable-num")
def pointer_capture(evt):
    print("ptrdown",evt)
    if not(evt.button != 0 or evt.ctrlKey):
        evt.target.dragging = {dx: evt.target.pos.x - evt.clientX}
        evt.target.setPointerCapture(evt.pointerId)

@when("pointermove", selector=".scrubbable-num")
def getpos(evt):
    if evt.target.dragging:
        x = evt.clientX
        evt.target.pos.x = clamp(x + evt.target.dragging.dx, 0, 1000)
        evt.target.el.value = round(evt.target.pos.x)

@when("pointercancel", selector=".scrubbable-num")
def pointer_up(evt):
    evt.target.onpointerup(evt)

@when("touchstart",selector=".scrubbable-num")
@when("dragstart",selector=".scrubbable-num")
def prevent_default(evt):
    evt.target.preventDefault()
```

In `evt.target.dragging = {dx: evt.target.pos.x - evt.clientX}` this is obviously js and fails.
How do I do something similar?

Comment: In addition to the answer below, I'm not sure if `pos` is an actual attribute of an HTML element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to create a JavaScript object from within Python is to use Pyodide's [to_js](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/api/python-api/ffi.html#pyodide.ffi.to_js) function, especially when passing `Object.fromEntries` as the conversion method.

```py
from pyodide.ffi import to_js
from js import Object

evt.target.dragging = to_js(
    {'dx': 1234},
    dict_converter = Object.fromEntries
)

# Creates a JS Object: {dx: 1234}
```

Note that the keys in the python dict are strings, which get converted to attributes of the JavaScript object.

Edit: here's a working version of your code, at least from what I understand the intent to be. Only a couple of other minor changes were needed, and these may be unnecessary based on any surrounding code not shown in your example, so feel free to take or leave them:

- `clamp` is a JavaScript function, re-implemented here in Python
- `pos` is not a default attribute of an HTML element and wasn't initialized, so I've condensed the two lines where it was used into one.
- The scrolling, I guessed, wanted to be relative to whatever it was at the start of the click-and-drag

```py
from pyscript import when 
from pyodide.ffi import to_js
from js import Object, console

def clamp(value, minimum, maximum):
    return max(minimum, min(value, maximum))

@when("pointerup", selector=".scrubbable-num")
def nodrag(evt):
    evt.target.dragging = None

@when("pointerdown", selector=".scrubbable-num")
def pointer_capture(evt):
    print("ptrdown",evt)
    targetPosition = evt.target.getBoundingClientRect()
    if not(evt.button != 0 or evt.ctrlKey):
        evt.target.dragging = to_js({'dx': targetPosition.x - evt.clientX}, dict_converter=Object.fromEntries)
        
        # make changes relative to initial value, or 0 if none is set
        evt.target.initialValue = int(evt.target.value) if evt.target.value else 0 
        evt.target.setPointerCapture(evt.pointerId)

@when("pointermove", selector=".scrubbable-num")
def getpos(evt):
    if hasattr(evt.target, "dragging"):
        x = evt.clientX
        evt.target.value = evt.target.initialValue + round(clamp(x + evt.target.dragging.dx, -1000, 1000))

@when("pointercancel", selector=".scrubbable-num")
def pointer_up(evt):
    evt.target.onpointerup(evt)

@when("touchstart",selector=".scrubbable-num")
@when("dragstart",selector=".scrubbable-num")
def prevent_default(evt):
    evt.target.preventDefault()
```

Comment: This is working very well except for the `evt.target.getBoundingClientRect()` section which changes the value depending on where you enter the input field. Solution to this below. But accepted answer because it answers the question by using to_js. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Jeff's answer shows how to add the javascript info to the js variable so is the best answer.

Below is a working solution which gives a more numerically stable result and incorporates (as Jeff added) the setting of an initial value.

This code does not need the `to_js()` additions as it turns out there is another way to do it - add attributes to the event class.
(It also has better named functions.)

The one remaining problem I have is that dragging does not propagate up to the input event and so, as the mouse moves I do not get a continuous series of input events (as I do when numerically entering/editing a value). So perhaps I need to generate an `Event("input")` in `input_drag()`.

- I thought preventDefault was stopping the bubbling up but commenting these out has no effect. (They are for handling browsers like Firefox which behaves slightly differently.)

Here is the input definition from the pyscript code which constructs the UI.
(Adding this to the inner html to create the input field):

```html
'<input id="%s-scrubbable" class="scrub-num" pattern="[0-9]+" py-input="update_UI()">' %(id)
```

The useful part of the css:

```css
.scrub-num {
    width: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: ew-resize; }
```

And the pyscript code:

```py
def clamp(value, minimum, maximum):
    return max(minimum, min(value, maximum))

@when("pointerdown", selector=".scrubbable-num")
def input_initiate_drag(evt):
    if not(evt.button != 0 ): # allow manual numeric entry to override
        # make changes relative to initial value, or 0 if none is set
        evt.target.initialValue = int(evt.target.value) if evt.target.value else 0 
        # remember our startX
        evt.target.xoffset = evt.target.initialValue - evt.clientX
        evt.target.setPointerCapture(evt.pointerId)

@when("pointermove", selector=".scrubbable-num")
def input_drag(evt):
    if hasattr(evt.target, "xoffset") and evt.target.xoffset:
        x = evt.clientX
        evt.target.value = round(clamp(x + evt.target.xoffset, -270, 270))
        # we need to fire an input(maybe) event so the UI can continue to update while dragging

@when("pointerup", selector=".scrubbable-num")
def input_stop_drag(evt):
    evt.target.xoffset = None

# if the browser takes over
@when("pointercancel", selector=".scrubbable-num")
def pointer_up(evt):
    evt.target.onpointerup(evt)

# for some browsers
@when("touchstart",selector=".scrubbable-num")
@when("dragstart",selector=".scrubbable-num")
def prevent_default(evt):
    evt.target.preventDefault()
```

Comment: In fact I canget the desired effect by changing the html and adding `py-mouseup="update_UI()"` I should probably try to rewrite this entirely using `py-drag` etc events and not the @when mechanism

Comment: This is great stuff @Neon22!